# Is there automatic SSL certificate renewal?

Tags: ssl, renew

At the moment, I am replacing my SSL certificate every year, which means copying around keys and stuff. I could get a two-year certificate, then I would do this every two years.

And having some customers who need this as a service from me, I thought about an automatic solution, that does the whole process itself. I know for managed servers this is done by the hosting company, but most of the machines I take care of are dedicated root servers.

Is there maybe a tool for this? Is there a standard protocol for it? A vendor with a special API? I'm looking for any solution that reduces my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namecheap offers an API for their SSL offerings. For example, [renewal](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/ssl/renew.aspx):

```
https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=apiexample&ApiKey=56b4c87ef4fd49cb96d915c0db68194&UserName=apiexample&command=namecheap.ssl.renew&clientip=1.2.3.4&certificateid=501904&ssltype=positivessl&years=1
```

Comment: That's promising, thanks! If you find a howto for the common web servers, it could improve the answer, but will accept it now. Hope it's not more work to set it up than what i do now :)